# How to get a series of elements to loop through showing only one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, loops

I am attempting to get my span elements `agencyText` to appear one at a time. Then at the end of the interval for the `curr` and `next` classes to be applied to properly position the current and next bit of text to appear.

As of now, I am getting them all shown at once. I created them with data attribute index values. However, I am unsure how to loop through them to get this to work correctly.

[If you click this link](https://www.bowenmedia.com/) there is an example of the left side of exactly what I am trying to do. It is the text rotated 90 degrees. Every four seconds the wording is updated.

Does anyone know how I can modify my code to replicate this?

UPDATE - showing DOM code of example.

[image]

```js
var arr = $('.textContainer');
var arrLen = arr.length;
var i = 0;
var attr = $('agencyText').data('index');

var loop = function() {  
  var item = arr.eq(i);
  var description = item.find('.agencyText');

  description.addClass('curr');

  i = (i + 1) % arrLen;
};
loop();
setInterval(loop, 3000);
```

```css
.digitalAgency {
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: -45%;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
 -webkit-transition:opacity .5s;
 -o-transition:opacity .5s;
 transition:opacity .5s;
}
.digitalAgency .textContainer::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 40px;
 height: 1px;
 background: #000;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 50%;
 margin-right: 20px;
 left: 33%;
}
.digitalAgency .textContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 650px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
.digitalAgency, .agencyText {
    -webkit-animation-duration: .45s;
    animation-duration: .45s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.digitalAgency .textContainer .agencyText {
    padding-left: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 33%;
}
.digitalAgency .textContainer .agencyText.curr {
 visibility: visible;
}
.digitalAgency .agencyText.curr{visibility:visible;-webkit-animation-name:dgAgnCurr;animation-name:dgAgnCurr}
.digitalAgency .agencyText.next{visibility:visible;-webkit-animation-name:dgAgnNext;animation-name:dgAgnNext}
@-webkit-keyframes dgAgnCurr{from{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}to{-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);transform:translateY(-100%)}}
@keyframes dgAgnCurr{from{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}to{-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);transform:translateY(-100%)}}
@-webkit-keyframes dgAgnNext{from{-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);transform:translateY(100%)}to{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}}
@keyframes dgAgnNext{from{-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);transform:translateY(100%)}to{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="digitalAgency">
  <span class="textContainer">
    <span data-index="0" class="agencyText">The first one</span>
    <span data-index="1" class="agencyText">The second one</span>
    <span data-index="2" class="agencyText">The third one</span>
    <span data-index="3" class="agencyText">The fourth one</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add the class `next` makes it visible in your original code. Using Syed's code below, adding the `next` class and changing the visibility to hidden results in [Sample Pen](https://codepen.io/DaveA/pen/JVwaoe). Probably need to tweak the animation to get the rolling feature of your sample.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Thanks for the help. That is perfect! I appreciate it.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Could you explain how this work and loops over? ('span[data-index = '+i+']').addClass('curr');i = (i + 1) % arrLen; I am wanting to understand how this work in JS.

Comment: The line `$('span[data-index = '+i+']').addClass('curr');` is doing a jQuery attribute selector inserting the `i` variable. You example has 4 span elements with index attributes of zero to 4 (so only 0,1,2,3 are valid). To continuously loop the values 0 to 3 Syed used the modulo % (remainder) operand. i is 0, add 1, divide by arrLen (4) and the remainder is 1 - now the index is one. When you hit i = 3 (last one) then i is 3, add 1 to get 4, divide by 4 and get 1 with a remainder of zero and loop again at the beginning - `i` only get's set to the remainder. Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your javascript code. try like this

```js
var arr = $('.textContainer > span');
var arrLen = arr.length;
var i = 0;

var loop = function() {  
  $('.textContainer > span').removeClass('curr');
  $('span[data-index = '+i+']').addClass('curr');
  
  i = (i + 1) % arrLen;
  
};
loop();
setInterval(loop, 3000);
```

```css
.digitalAgency {
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: -45%;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
 -webkit-transition: opacity .5s;
    -o-transition: opacity .5s;
    transition: opacity .5s;
 -webkit-transition:opacity .5s;
 -o-transition:opacity .5s;
 transition:opacity .5s;
}
.digitalAgency .textContainer::before {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 40px;
 height: 1px;
 background: #000;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 50%;
 margin-right: 20px;
 left: 33%;
}
.digitalAgency .textContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 650px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(-90deg);
    display: inline-block;
}
.digitalAgency, .agencyText {
    -webkit-animation-duration: .45s;
    animation-duration: .45s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
.digitalAgency .textContainer .agencyText {
    padding-left: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 33%;
}
.digitalAgency .textContainer .agencyText.curr {
 visibility: visible;
}
.digitalAgency .agencyText.curr{visibility:visible;-webkit-animation-name:dgAgnCurr;animation-name:dgAgnCurr}
.digitalAgency .agencyText.next{visibility:visible;-webkit-animation-name:dgAgnNext;animation-name:dgAgnNext}
@-webkit-keyframes dgAgnCurr{from{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}to{-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);transform:translateY(-100%)}}
@keyframes dgAgnCurr{from{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}to{-webkit-transform:translateY(-100%);transform:translateY(-100%)}}
@-webkit-keyframes dgAgnNext{from{-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);transform:translateY(100%)}to{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}}
@keyframes dgAgnNext{from{-webkit-transform:translateY(100%);transform:translateY(100%)}to{-webkit-transform:translateY(0);transform:translateY(0)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="digitalAgency">
  <span class="textContainer">
    <span data-index="0" class="agencyText">The first one</span>
    <span data-index="1" class="agencyText">The second one</span>
    <span data-index="2" class="agencyText">The third one</span>
    <span data-index="3" class="agencyText">The fourth one</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of doing this `$('span').removeClass('curr')`. How could I add the `next` class to the element that is next?

Comment: you can use like `$('.textContainer > span').removeClass('curr')`

Comment: I'm saying instead of using the `removeClass`, I have a css class called `next` that has a keyframe that repositions the element that will be next to be looped...it also has other css properties associated with it. How could this code be modified to find the next element in the loop (before it is shown in the interval) and then add the `next` class? You will see what I mean if you look at the source code of the example site. I added an img to my question of the console showing this in the DOM to help illustrate.

Comment: you can add a `next` class to the next element like 
`$('span[data-index = '+(i+1)+']').addClass('next');`

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you explain how this work and loops over? `('span[data-index = '+i+']').addClass('curr');i = (i + 1) % arrLen;` I am wanting to understand how this work in JS.

Comment: it searches for the span tag which contains data attribute of `data-index` is equal to the `i` value and add the class `curr`